# Stylable marker/feature in react-mapbox-gl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

Im using https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl

My question is how to style the marker or feature component?

Feature **does not** accept children nor style prop.

Marker accepts style and children, however it doesnt render anything passed as props and even if I style it with, e.g. `{{ background: 'blue' }}` it has no any effects on the style.

Have I missed something? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marker and Feature are two different components which work in different ways but can both achieve what you are trying to do. Let's start with Markers.

**Marker Styling**

You will note that in the [react-mapbox-gl documentation](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/API.md#marker) that the `style` attribute will only effect the marker's container, not the marker itself. If you want to change the style of a Marker you should pass in your own marker as a child to the Marker component. Failing to pass in a child will result in the default light blue, droplet shaped marker being used. Note that this child you pass in as the marker could be a custom svg or even an [html component that is styled with CSS](https://codepen.io/katia-trifonova/pen/zwZgdx).

```
<Marker
  coordinates={[-0.2416815, 51.5285582]}
  anchor="bottom">
  <img src={linkToMyCustomMarker}/>
</Marker>
```

or...

```
<Marker
  coordinates={[-0.2416815, 51.5285582]}
  anchor="bottom">
  <div class="mapMarkerStyle"></div>
</Marker>
```

Here's a Code Sandbox showing this in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/my2p15knj8

**Layer Styling**

In order to style Features you will first need to use the Layer component, as mentioned in the [documentation for Feature](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/API.md#feature). In the [documentation for the Layer component](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/API.md#feature) you can see that you must set up your layer first and then pass in the Feature component(s) as a child for every location on the map that you would like to render this Layer. Like so:

```
<Layer type="circle" id="marker" paint={{
  'circle-color': "#ff5200",
  'circle-stroke-width': 1,
  'circle-stroke-color': '#fff',
  'circle-stroke-opacity': 1
 }}>
  <Feature coordinates={[-0.132,51.518]}/>
  <Feature coordinates={[-0.465,51.258]}/>
</Layer>
```

Here is a Code Sandbox showing the above in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/l42n3np7xm

In order to change the look and feel of the Layer that is displayed you can play around with the `layout` property on the Layer component. All of the settings that you can change can be found in the [Mapbox Style Definition](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers-symbol).

Comment: Unfortunately none of your proposals regarding marker did work. Marker stays the same even if I pass children to it. Whats more - even if I pass inline styles to it, nothing changes...

Comment: Perhaps you could create a CodePen that recreates the issue, so that I can better understand?

Comment: Here you go, as you can see nothing happens with the Marker :( https://codesandbox.io/s/8x2pmzkj59

Comment: Just updated my answer with Code Sandboxes showing you how to get things working. I think that you need to read my answer more closely because in your Sandbox you have <Marker> components within a <Layer> component, which I specifically mention won't work.

Comment: I'm trying to use  a custom Feature component (that returns a `<Feature />`), but unless it's direct child is a pure `<Feature />`, it's giving the error "cannot read property 0 of undefined"?